# Swift - How to Properly Implement Updating/Setting Up of CoreData for use prior to ViewController loading

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, appdelegate, updating

My situation is as follows:

I will be using CoreData to store/fetch entity instances to be displayed in a tableView. At the start of the app, I have the app check the version of the current library, then - if necessary - download an updated version (via JSON).

The problem (I believe) is that the View Controller loads and crashes when it attempts to pull the tableView information from the data source before the  "version check" and "library updates" to CoreData have completed. Since the update has not completed, the library has no instances of the entity saved and returns a nil value for the rows to be displayed - causing the crash.

My question is: What is the proper way to implement the updating feature and ensure that all "version" checks and "library" updates are completed before the initial view controller is loaded and attempts to retrieve the necessary information to display the tableView.

I assume it has something to do with "willFinishLaunchingWithOptions" in App Delegate, but I am stuck in terms of how to set it up. As you might have guessed, I am new to coding; therefore, detailed responses would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To perform some lengthy task (such as implementing the updating feature like "version" checks and "library" updates), follow the following approach:-

1. Create a view controller which is similar to splash view controller, say `CustomSplashViewController`
2. In CustomSplashViewController, perform the version checks and library updates task
3. After completion of updates check, navigate to your home view controller.
4. If mandatory updates fail at CustomSplashViewController, then show the popup with try again button.